# How can I generate a variably-sized matrix of random values in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

How can I generate a random matrix with more rows than columns? For example, with the number of rows being a multiple of the number of columns, like `10 columns 500 rows`, or `20 columns 1000 rows`, etc...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do these sorts of things using functions like [RAND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rand.html) and [RANDI](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randi.html). For example:

```
nCols = randi([10 20]);   %# A random integer between 10 and 20
nRows = nCols*50;         %# Number of rows is a multiple of number of columns
mat = rand(nRows,nCols);  %# A matrix of random values between 0 and 1
```